# unresolved reference 'path' - django

Tags: python, django

I installed python 3.6.2 and django 1.11.6. I then added 'pip' and 'django' path inside "PATH" variable in environmental variables in both sections

#### User Variables :

> C:\Users\Moh3n\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts
> C:\Users\Moh3n\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\django
> C:\Users\Moh3n\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages

#### System Variables  :

> c:\Users\Moh3n\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts
> C:\Users\Moh3n\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages
> C:\Users\Moh3n\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\django

Then I created a project with `django` and created a simple app named `polls`.

In `polls/urls.py` I added the import statement `from django.urls import path`

[image: polls/urls.py]

Then pycharm poped a box saying

```
unresolved reference 'path'
```

I didn't pay attention at first and then in `mysite/urls.py` added the same import statement.

[image: mysite/urls.py]

The same thing happened for `include, path`. At the end when I ran server in cmdier with the code

```
py manage.py runserver
```

I saw this traceback:

[image: Traceback]

If you could help me to find where the problem is, I'd really appreciate.

Comment: (because I neet at least 10 reputation to post mor than 2 links I placed my image url here:)

i.stack.imgur.com/BYK3S.png

Comment: Is there any real reason why you added the path to "site-packages" and "django" to the environment variables? I don't think that's the source of the error, but there's no need to do that.

Comment: Simple reason: You're working with Django 1.11, but you use the documentation of Django 2. There is no `path` to import from `django.urls` in Django 1.x.

Comment: There's a reason why StackOverflow is making it difficult for you to insert images. They're unsearchable, impossible to copy and paste, and hard to read on smaller screens. **None of these should be images**. Post them as *text*.

Answer (score 5):

use this

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
```

Answer (score 0):

To check for outdated packages using pip type:

```
pip list --outdated
```

Then install the latest Django version. (At this time it is 2.0.3).  Using this command (altering the version number if needed).

```
pip install django==2.0.3
```

This will update your Django installation and allow you to use the [latest Django  tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/).